# how to convert a file from DOS to Unix

Tags: powershell, dos2unix

I need to convert a file from DOS to Unix in PowerShell.

I know this can be very much easily done in Unix:

```
dos2unix file newfile
```

Comment: Why not do the conversion in the *nix system? Or use Cygwin's tools for the same instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: [Replace CRLF using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19127741/995714)

Answer (score 9):

It could be as simple as

```
Get-Content in.csv -raw | % {$_ -replace "`r", ""} | Set-Content -NoNewline out.csv
```

Above method will work on powershell version 3+. If you are below that you can use below method instead. Almost same as one of the other answers here.

```
$csvdata = [io.file]::ReadAllText('in.csv') | % {$_ -replace "`r",""}
[io.file]::WriteAllLines('out.csv', $csvdata)
```

Comment: `-NoNewline` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Updated my answer with a version that works pre v3.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$txt = (Get-Content -Raw myFile.txt) -replace "`r`n","`n"
[io.file]::WriteAllText('c:\path\to\myFile.unix.txt', $txt)
```

I used `WriteAllText` rather than `Set-Content` because `Set-Content` adds a carriage return and a line feed to the end of the file, and there doesn't seem to be any way to suppress that.

I think that the `-Raw` parameter to `Get-Content` might be a PowerShell 3 thing, so if you are using an earlier version, you might need to do it like this:

```
$txt = [io.file]::ReadAllText('c:\path\to\myFile.txt') -replace "`r`n","`n"
[io.file]::WriteAllText('c:\path\to\myFile.unix.txt', $txt)
```

Comment: Yes, the parameter `-Raw` exists only in PowerShell v3 and above. However, if you're writing with a .NET method I'd use a .NET method for reading anyway, if only for symmetry reasons.

Comment: The first part worked like a charm!