# Gawk Print puzzling behavior

Tags: awk

A csv file has two columns.
The code below outputs the entire file (all rows and the two columns separated by a comma)

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
{print $0}
```

However, the code below, outputs only one value viz. the Column 1 of the first row:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
{print $1}
```

Above code is a .awk file and run in Windows using the command gawk -f test.awk xyz.csv > output.csv

What am I doing wrong?

Edited:
Output after changing the {Print $1} to "`{print "<" NR "><" $1 "><" $0 ">"}`"``

```
<1><naskar><naskar,sahoo ,1
sahoo ,18290,
ree ,6379,
mukherjee ,4609,
```

Comment: This can't happen unless you have stray characters in your `xyz.csv`. Post the output of `file xyz.csv`

Comment: The output when $1 is used is "naskar"

Comment: The output when $0 is used is "naskar, sahoo" and all the rest of the rows in the file below that.

Comment: I think there is something wrong ("stray characters")  with the file as the Gawk commands are working as expected in another file. How do I identity and fix the problem that is causing this odd behavior?

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks.  I think your inference is correct. The file does not seem to be a DOS file. Is there any way of visually or otherwise determining whether the file is DOS or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255747/on-windows-how-would-i-detect-the-line-ending-of-a-file , gives a link to unix tool `file`, or how to check it in notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling gawk as `gawk -v RS='\n' ...` since the most likely problem is that you have UNIX line endings (`\n`) in your input file but your call to gawk is expecting DOS line endings (`\r\n`) and so thinks the file is a single line. If that's not it then change `{print $1}` to `{print "<" NR "><" $1 "><" $0 ">"}` and create a file with 5 lines run the script on it then edit your question to show the input file and the output you get.

Comment: Is there any way to visually or otherwise determine whether the file has DOS line endings (for use in future)?

Comment: I don't know Windows tools but on UNIX you can run the `file` command on it or run `cat -Ev` on it. On Windows you can install `cygwin` or similar to get a UNIX environment to run UNIX tools from. I updated my comment to be an answer since that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Under windows you can create a batchfile like this:

```
@echo off
powershell -Command "write \"$(\"CRLF:\") - $((Get-Content '%1' -Raw) -match '\r\n$')\""
powershell -Command "write \"$(\"CR:\") - $((Get-Content '%1' -Raw) -match '\r$')\""
powershell -Command "write \"$(\"LF:\") - $((Get-Content '%1' -Raw) -match '\n$')\""
```

It will output something like this for a file with LF as line separator:

```
D:\TEMP>file.bat textfile.txt
CRLF: - False
CR: - False
LF: - True
D:\TEMP>
```