# Batch script to Replace CR by CRLF in in text file

Tags: windows, file, text, carriage-return

I Want to create batch script to replace carriage return(CR) by CRLF (carriage return and Line Feed).It should be use for other text file also, I can replace that in notepad++ but want to replace for more than 1 file so need to create a separate batch file which on execution replace that CR by CRLF. Can anyone help me out in these situation.

Thank You

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127741/replace-crlf-using-powershell and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626938/powershell-v2-replace-crlf-with-lf ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use notepad++ itself to mass replace

open a command prompt 
type notepad++.exe -noseesion -r *.*

this will open all the files in a directory only without any files from previous 
session

hit ctrl+h and replace in all documents

```
C:\massreplace>ls
001.bin                               001.txt  002.txt  004.txt
001.mysuperdupersecretsauceextension  001.yuk  003.txt  005.txt

C:\massreplace>"c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -nosession  -r *.*

C:\massreplace>
```

see in the screen shot below all the 8 files are open 
each files has 39 lines and 38 lines have CRLF
i replaced all 38*8 = 304 CRLF with LF by hitting 
REPLACE all in all opened documents

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I want to create batch file for this process so that I can use this in another workflows.

Comment: Means I want to create such a batch file that can use for multiple text files.

Comment: well whatever the -r *.* opens multiple text /whatever files