# Composing a string in script shell

Tags: shell

So I'm trying to compose a string using script shell

```
#!/bin/sh
blNumber=1111619832
echo '*'$blNumber+='*.xlsx'
```

I expect the output to be: `*1111619832*.xlsx`
but as a result I get: `*+=*.xlsx`

Btw I tried to figure out why so I tried this code

```
#!/bin/sh
blNumber=1111619832
output="*${blNumber}"
```

and whenever I add something after `*${blNumber}` it get concatenated at the begging of the string

Comment: Watch your shebang! [`sh` isn't necessarily `bash`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/4518341)

Comment: @HamaLAHLOU : Removed bash tag, because the question is not bash-related.

Comment: @HamaLAHLOU : Just use `b1Numer="$b1Number.xlsx"`, or more general, `b1Numer="${b1Number}.xlsx"`

Comment: @HamzaLAHOU : You can - with few exceptions, which don't apply here - not modify a variable inside another statement. You have to first write a statement which changes the variable, and then you can use it in  i.e. an `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `+=` in the first place?

```
$ echo '*'$blNumber'*.xlsx'
*1111619832*.xlsx
```

Or put it inside double-quotes. It's best practice to quote all variables anyway.

```
$ echo "*$blNumber*.xlsx"
*1111619832*.xlsx
```

Comment: I tried your solution but ut's not working. the output : *.xlsx19832

Comment: @Hamza It looks like you have Windows line endings. See [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF) in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/4518341)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368781/anything-like-dos2unix-for-windows

Comment: the link above solved the issue on notepad++